# how to do joins on Firebase tables

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am trying to get data from two tables like (fetch all users and their details)

```
tableOne.on('users', function (snapshot) {
    userId = snapshot.val().userId; // line 1 (results like 1,2,3,4,5,6)
    anotherTable.child('userdetails').child(userId).once('value', function(mediaSnap) {
     // result // line 2
 });
});
```

but the problem is line 1 executes first for the 6 times and then line 2 that n times resulting in everytime looking for 'where user id is - 6'...isn't joins supported in Firebase?

Any help is apreciated

Comment: You should probably read this article: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-10-01-queries-part-one.html#join and consider using this library: http://firebase.github.io/firebase-util/. Also note that `on('users'` is not a valid event. You're probably lookinig for `on('value'` or `on('child_added'`.

Comment: Frank, I was working on first link only but problem is they are fetching single details and I want to fetch all the details from first table and corresponding details from second table

Comment: second link looks better, will look if it can help me...thanks

Comment: I tried reproducing your problem based on the code you provided, but without success (after I change `on('users'` to `on('child_added'`). Can you update this jsbin so that it reproduces the problem? http://jsbin.com/zifeqi/1/edit

Comment: Thanks Frank that was wonderful effort done by you...yes I have changed the code ...pls see the console you will see the result set has same user id

Comment: http://jsbin.com/maxigutifepi/2/edit

Comment: OK. Now type `var` in front of the `userId` variable **inside** the `tableOne.on('value', function` function. I just did and that ensures that I see 6 distinct userId values. http://jsbin.com/maxigutifepi/5/watch?js,console

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen great suggestion. It might be worth noting that firebase-utils is not compatible with the latest Firebase. I don't believe Google has done a great job making that clear if you land on the firebase-utils project page. I just burned about an hour researching this cool technology that I can't use. :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code snippet has a nasty side-effect:

```
var userId;
tableOne.on('value', function (snapshot) {
    userId = snapshot.val().userId; // line 1 (results like 1,2,3,4,5,6)
    anotherTable.child('userdetails').child(userId).once('value', function(mediaSnap) {
        console.log(userId + ":" + mediaSnap.val().name);
    });
});
```

You're not declaring `userId` as a variable, which means that it becomes a global variable in JavaScript. And since the callback function executes asynchronously, there is a good chance that the global values will have changed by the time you need it.

The solution is simply to make `userId` a local variable of the callback function:

```
tableOne.on('value', function (snapshot) {
    var userId = snapshot.val().userId; // line 1 (results like 1,2,3,4,5,6)
    anotherTable.child('userdetails').child(userId).once('value', function(mediaSnap) {
        console.log(userId + ":" + mediaSnap.val().name);
    });
});
```

This will ensure that each value of `userId` is captured inside the function.

Comment: Frank, thanks but that was not the complete code, ofcourse userid is a local variable which I have declared just above the join, and the problem is line 1 is executing for 6 times first so it will override value of userId and the last value will be used in next query

Comment: Even if you define `userId` above the join, it will still be shared by all callbacks. And since the callbacks fire asynchronously (and often in batches), your problems are likely caused by that.

Comment: Thanks for all the solutions....but 1) after this the getPriority has changed the content's order, I had the priority set in first table but after join the data sequence is different....2) isn't order by supported without priority?

Comment: Read this section of the documentation: https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-rest-ordered-data. It does a good job of explaining ordering of nodes. Also be sure to peruse the existing questions about Firebase and order here on StackOverflow. This topic comes up regularly.

Comment: Frank, I was already using the priority on the first table to fetch data in the required format and it works well before joining the two tables, after joining the data is messed up

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen is it acceptable to do three joins since Im attempting to join three nodes for the view I am populating!?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for list join:**

```
tableOne.orderByKey().on("value", function (snapshot) {
    //console.log(snapshot.val());
    snapshot.forEach(function (data) {
        tableTwo.once('value').then(function (info) {
            info = info.val();
        });
    });
});
```