# FIRDatabaseQuery: how to do an inner join

Tags: ios, firebase, inner-join, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to do an inner join on a FIRDatabaseQuery object.

below is the database structure. I have some posts that are linked to post-comments. I am trying to get all the posts that a specific user added a comment on:

```
 {
   "posts" : {
    "-KIycKhZU55dmKnHbbxv" : {
      "author" : "John Doe",
      "body" : "This is a post test",
      "title" : "test",
      "uid" : "SHaH36BLwgPvwgi9cDmRnsnONFB2"
    },
    "-KIyg_ks1O5QL4_4dfq_" : {
      "author" : "Jane Doe",
      "body" : "This is a post test",
      "title" : "test2",
      "uid" : "x5leSBGArnd10JilD9YDyNBNfZ03"
    },...
   }
  "post-comments" : {
    "-KIycKhZU55dmKnHbbxv" : {
      "-KIycMyL0Vy1BHVdI4zc" : {
        "author" : "toto",
        "text" : "test",
        "uid" : "SHaH36BLwgPvwgi9cDmRnsnONFB2"
      },
      "-KIyg_ks1O5QL4_4dfq_" : {
        "author" : "toto",
        "text" : "test",
        "uid" : "SHaH36BLwgPvwgi9cDmRnsnONFB2"
      }
    },...
 }
```

in SQL this will be translated into a inner join query similar to:

Select * from post inner join post-comments on post-id where post-comments.uid = "user id"

Does anybody know how o get something similar to an inner join in firebase?

Thanks a lot,
Yacine

Comment: just made some updates in my answer. let me know if it was usefull. :)

Comment: You could also alter your data structure slightly and have a node within each user object and within that node hold the id's to all the posts they have commented on. You just can just store the id of the post as a key, and the value can be true.

Comment: thanks for your feedback as well DogCoffee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to work with nested firebase calls. You can find a [javascript example in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25712083/how-to-do-joins-on-firebase-tables) but your swift code should look like the following:

```
ref.child("posts").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
    if let postId = snapshot.key as! String {
      let commentsRef = ref.child("post-comments")  
      commentsRef.child(postId).queryOrderedByChild("uid").queryEqualToValue(userId).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as [FDataSnapshot] {
               print(child.value)     
            }
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
      }
})
```

Comment: sorry if there is any swift related problem with the code. Couldn't test it.

Comment: @Yacine It appears this proposing iterating over every post in the database and querying each one individually for the uid in question. If there's 1,000,000 posts, that may take a while. And, as the database grows it would take longer and longer.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to consider

```
"posts" : {
    "-KIycKhZU55dmKnHbbxv" : {
      "author" : "John Doe",
      "body" : "This is a post test",
      "title" : "test",
      "uid" : "SHaH36BLwgPvwgi9cDmRnsnONFB2"
      "commented_by"
           "SHaH36BLwgPvwgi9cDmRnsnONFB2": true
```

Then you can simply query for

```
posts.child("commented_by/uid").queryEqualToValue(true)
```

or, change the post-comments around to better match the queries you want to do:

```
"post-comments" : {
  "-KIycMyL0Vy1BHVdI4zc" : {
     "author" : "toto",
     "post_data":
          post_id: "-KIycKhZU55dmKnHbbxv",
          post_title: "test"
     "text" : "test",
     "uid" : "SHaH36BLwgPvwgi9cDmRnsnONFB2"
},
```

That makes the query a snap as the post-comments node can be queried for the uid which return all of the post_id's of the posts they commented on. It wouldn't return the post itself, however, you may just be looking for the title so you can populate a list. Once the user taps it clicks it you can retrieve the actual data.

Comment: Nice answer @Jay I forgot to point out this in my answer but since he was asking on how to do an inner "sql-like" query I focused on it. But you are right, he should think on some redesigns on his schema.

Comment: Thanks for the input Jay! That is a great insight to not neglect the scalability aspect. I will use this to rework the schema.