# How to multiple join query in firebase?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

i'm using react native with firebase@2.4.2. I find very difficult to perform multiple join query. Can someone guide me or is there a library for multiple join?

Below is my data structure and i want to join them.

```
chats: {
 chatID1: {
  lastMessage: "Hi",
  userID: "userID1"
 },
 chatID2: {
  lastMessage: "Hahahahahhaa",
  userID: "userID2"
 }
}

users: {
 userID1: {
  name: "vzhen"
 },
 userID2: {
  name: "ITshop"
 }
}
```

UPDATE

```
listenForChats(chatsRef) {
    chatsRef.on("value", (chatsSnap) => {
        var chats = [];

        chatsSnap.forEach(chatSnap => {

            this.usersRef.child(chatSnap.val().sellerID).on('value', (userRef) => {
                alert(userRef.val().name);
            })

            chats.push({
                lastMessage: chatSnap.val().lastMessage,
                name: //HOW TO PASS userRef.val() TO HERE?
            })

        })


        //IGNORE THIS LINE - react native thingy
        this.setState({
            dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(chats)
        });
    })
}
```

ANSWERED

from vzsg and FrankvanPuffelen
`this.setState()` should be inside `forEach() {}` otherwise, no one will know that you have new data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FIRDatabaseQuery: how to do an inner join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38033464/firdatabasequery-how-to-do-an-inner-join)

Comment: @adolfosrs that is for Swift, this question is for React Native.

Comment: @vzhen: did you try anything yet? Simple loading a single item type is the least you must already have working. Otherwise you're asking us to write your app for you, which is not how Stack Overflow works..

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i tried.  i'm now looking at adolfosrs link. wiil  update again if i meet a question

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  i updated my question with code, from my code i have problem pushing inner return to my chats array.

Comment: What's the use of the `this.usersRef.child(chatSnap.val().sellerID).on('value'` listener? All you do is alert it. If you remove that, how does that relate to the behavior you want? (I'm asking, because you're calling `this.setState()` before the user name is loaded)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  yup, you are right. this.setState() should be inside 
 forEach().  I just got the answer from vzsg in slack.

Comment: For cross-posting across multiple channels, you now get the honor of self-answering here.