# How to display data that depends on other entity?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Having the following data:

```
"animals" : {
    "a1" : {
      "name" : "Dog"
    },
    "a2" : {
      "name" : "Cat"
    },
    "a3" : {
      "name" : "Cow"
    }
  },

  "users" : {
    "u1" : {
      "favAnimals" : {
        "a1" : true,
        "a2" : true
      },
      "name" : "Danilo"
    }
  }
```

How can I display for the user, using the FirebaseListAdapter, the complete list of animals, highlighing user's favorite animals?

Is it possible to query and join them, to get a Database Reference that would watch for changes both in "/animals" and "/users/$uid/favAnimals" and return something like:

```
"animals" : {
    "a1" : {
      "name" : "Dog",
      "fav" : true
    },
    "a2" : {
      "name" : "Cat"
      "fav" : true
    },
    "a3" : {
      "name" : "Cow"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FIRDatabaseQuery: how to do an inner join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38033464/firdatabasequery-how-to-do-an-inner-join)

Comment: Don't think it is a duplicate. My question is more like an left join. I don't want to filter the animals, just highlight those the user chose. Also I want to do it using the firebase-ui adapter, if it is possible.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559171/coupling-firebaserecyclerviewadapter-to-a-boolean-string-map-entry for a way to change the data that the ListView displays from the type that is stored in the database. That should give you a decent starting point.