# How to join two tables in firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I created one table has `studId, studName, place`.I also want to create another table related to the first one that has `studId, day, timeone, timeTwo`. How can I do it? I'm a beginner in firebase

this method will add the data for firebase

```
private void addDate(){

    String studName = userName.getText().toString().trim();
    String place = spinnerPlace.getSelectedItem().toString();

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(studName)){

     String id = databaseStudentData.push().getKey();

     StudentData studentData = new StudentData(id, studName, place);

     databaseStudentData.child(id).setValue(studentData);
     addDay(id);

     Toast.makeText(this, "Data is saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "you Should Enter your name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

and here the data that i stored 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpjZ2.png)

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25712083/how-to-do-joins-on-firebase-tables

Comment: Show us a concrete example of what you want to achieve and what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

There is no benefit in creating another table just for one attribute, what you can do is the following. Since you already did this:

```
     String id = databaseStudentData.push().getKey();

     StudentData studentData = new StudentData(id, studName, place);

     databaseStudentData.child(id).setValue(studentData);
```

Now to add `time` under this table you can do the following:

```
 Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
 childUpdates.put("time", time);
 databaseStudentData.child(id).updateChildren(childUpdates);
```

This way you will have the following database:

```
id
 studId : "id"
 studName : "name"
 studPlace : "place"
 studTime : "time"
```

Comment: childUpdates.put("day", day); there is no **join** in nosql, if you want data that is under one node to be under another node then you need to do `setValue` again for example: `DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("timing");ref.child(id).child("studId").setValue(id);ref.child(id).child("time").setValue(time);ref.child(id).child("studName").setValue(name);` etc... for example...

Comment: @SaraAlmaqbali as I said in the comment if you want the data that is under one node to be under another node also + additonal data, then you need to create two reference and use `setValue()` for each. There is no join in nosql, you can add the data in multiple places. You should read this: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html