# How to return combine data with different tables in a loop function with Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my data structure in firebase realtime database.

[[image]

And I want to make an API to return the data combined with `toolbox` `toolboxUsers` `toolboxTools` for each toolbox.

Here is my code. I've tried many ways but no one works well.
I've also seem some reference like https://youtube.com/watch?v=Idu9EJPSxiY and [how to do joins on Firebase tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25712083/how-to-do-joins-on-firebase-tables/25712665#25712665)

**way 1**

```
  toolboxesRef.once('value', snapshot => {
    var toolboxes = []
    var toolboxKeys = Object.keys(snapshot.val());
    for(var toolboxKey of toolboxKeys) {
      var toolboxPromise = toolboxesRef.child(toolboxKey).once('value');
      var toolboxUsersPromise = toolboxUsersRef.child(toolboxKey).once('value');
      var toolboxToolsPromise = toolboxToolsRef.child(toolboxKey).once('value');
      Promise.all([toolboxPromise, toolboxUsersPromise, toolboxToolsPromise])
      .then(snapshot => {
        var toolbox = [];
        snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
          toolbox.push(childSnapshot.val());
        });
        toolboxes.push(toolbox);
      })
    }
    res.json(toolboxes);
  })
```

**way 2**

```
  toolboxesRef.once('value', snapshot => {
    var promises = [];
    snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
      var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
      var toolboxPromise = toolboxesRef.child(childKey).once('value');
      var toolboxUsersPromise = toolboxUsersRef.child(childKey).once('value');
      var toolboxToolsPromise = toolboxToolsRef.child(childKey).once('value');
      promises.push(toolboxPromise);
      promises.push(toolboxUsersPromise);
      promises.push(toolboxToolsPromise);
    });
    Promise.all(promises).then(snapshots => {
      var toolbox = [];
      snapshots.forEach(childSnapshot => {
        toolbox.push(childSnapshot.val());
      });
      res.json(toolbox);
  });
```

The result of I expected is get full data for each toolbox

[image]

But I can only get one toolbox data instead of the data for each toolbox, because it seems the for loop will execute first.

Can anyone give me some advises? Or is it the data structure wrong?

Comment: Which exact problem are you encountering? Using `Promise.all()` is the correct way for executing several asynchronous queries in //.

Comment: Yes. But I can only get one toolbox data instead of the data for each toolbox, because it seems the for loop will execute first.

Answer (score 0):

It would suit you better to avoid JOINS in a NoSQL datastore because that would mean your code will have to perform these joins and that can be very inefficient. The best approach for you in this scenario would be to create another structure which combines the data you have mentioned above.